# Looking for /procfs documentation, describing values and units of measurement

Tags: linux, process, memory, proc, documentation

Surprisingly, comprehensive documentation for `/procfs` is hard to find.
For my specific question, I am looking at: `cat /proc/1/statm` (let's use `pid=1` because it seems to be always there). I just ran this and got a result:

```
9370 954 341 210 0 727 0
```

1. Which one of these is resident memory?
2. What is it measured in?
3. How can I convert it to Megabytes?

Comment: Well, I found something useful here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt and the memory is computed in pages whereas one can tell what the page size is by running `$ getconf PAGESIZE` or `$ getconf PAGE_SIZE` which should equal `4096` on a typical Linux distro. I am still not sure what those numbers refer to. I searched for "1-4" without the quotes within the linked document to find the explanation. Also, in python one can do: `import resource; print resource.getpagesize()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540537/proc-pid-files-format

Comment: Oh, and this bit tells me that resident memory is the second number. http://www.lindevdoc.org/wiki//proc/pid/statm I wish this info was all in one place though.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is in [`Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) in the kernel source. Many distributions make it available through a package (e.g. `linux-doc` under Ubuntu, installing files under `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc`).

Here's the description of the `statm` fields from the documentation:

```
Field    Content
size     total program size (pages)     (same as VmSize in status)
resident size of memory portions (pages)    (same as VmRSS in status)
shared   number of pages that are shared    (i.e. backed by a file)
trs      number of pages that are 'code'    (not including libs; broken, includes data segment)
lrs      number of pages of library     (always 0 on 2.6)
drs      number of pages of data/stack      (including libs; broken, includes library text)
dt       number of dirty pages          (always 0 on 2.6)
```

This process has 954 pages in RAM. A page is 4kB on your system (it can be other values on exotic architectures or configurations; `getconf PAGESIZE` would confirm it). So that's a bit under 4MB.

The documentation isn't exhaustive. If you can't find what you're looking for, try searching on the [Linux Weekly News](http://lwn.net/) or elsewhere on the web. If you still can't find the answer, [use the source](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.7/fs/proc/).

Comment: There is also a `proc(5)` manpage on my debian system.

Comment: Ah, it is `man 5 proc`, not `man 5 procfs`. I have that on FC16 as well.

Comment: Hi @Gilles! Any ideas why `number of dirty pages          (always 0 on 2.6)`? Can't find the info about it... [question: http://superuser.com/questions/1001737/why-number-of-dirty-pages-is-always-0-on-2-6]